# Access model items in more than one template in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a view that is directed to the home page. In my home page, I have

```
{% for item in items %}
  {{ item.name }}<br>
  {{ item.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

I can't find a way to access the same items in another page. Writing the same code in that other page returns nothing.
How would I go about this here?

Comment: create another view in your views.py for another template, then pass your context in it. then you will access it.

Comment: @SerioUs. No other way, just that???

Comment: yes also you can create your custom template tags and load into your template.

Answer (score 1):

You need a way to reference the object (item) or queryset (items) that you passed into your homepage context. For each item, you can do this by passing the `pk`* of your Item object as a URL keyword argument (aka `kwarg`).

* 'pk' means 'primary key'. Like an ID number for each object.

Add this to your `urlpatterns` in `urls.py`:

```
path('items/<pk>/', views.item_detail, name='item_detail'),
```

Now you can "reverse" (ie. generate) URLs in your templates when given an appropriate `pk`, and a view name.

For example, in your homepage template code, you can create a link to each `item` like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'item_detail' pk=item.pk %}">{{ item.title }}</a>
```

Now, each link will generate a URL based on the `pk` of each Item object you've made.

If you load the HTML of the page when you view it, you will see that the {% url %} tag has been replaced by a URL, for example `http://localhost:8000/items/2/`.

Now, you can create an `item_detail` view in your `views.py` that will display the details of each Item:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from [your_app].models import Item

def item_detail(request, pk):

    item = Item.objects.get(pk=pk)

    return render(request, 'item_detail.html', {'item': item})
```

And create an HTML template for the new view in your `templates` directory (`item_detail.html`):

```
<h1>{{ item.name }}</h1>

<p>{{ item.title }}</p>
```

Now each page will automatically display the details for each object.